# Cant Upload doc format files in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|Doc';
```

I want to upload Doc format file only but cant upload doc format file just written The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Why?

How to solve issue,
I add mimes file,

```
'doc'   =>  'application/msword',
                'docx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/zip'),
                'xlsx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip'),
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this function

```
 public function do_upload(){
          $this->config =  array(
                  'upload_path'     => dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])."/files/",
                  'upload_url'      => base_url()."files/",
                  'allowed_types'   => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|doc|xml|docx|GIF|JPG|PNG|JPEG|PDF|DOC|XML|DOCX|xls|xlsx",

                  'overwrite'       => TRUE,
                  'max_size'        => "1000KB",
                  'max_height'      => "768",
                  'max_width'       => "1024"   
                );
        $this->remove_dir($this->config["upload_path"], false);

        $this->ci->load->library('upload', $this->config);
        if($this->ci->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $this->ci->data['status']->message = "File Uploaded Successfully";
            $this->ci->data['status']->success = TRUE;
            $this->ci->data["uploaded_file"] = $this->ci->upload->data();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->ci->data['status']->message = $this->ci->upload->display_errors();
            $this->ci->data['status']->success = FALSE;
        }
    }
```